# std::atomic<int> memory_order_relaxed VS volatile sig_atomic_t in a multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, volatile, memory-model, stdatomic

Does `volatile sig_atomic_t` give any memory order guarantees? E.g. if I need to just load/store an integer is it ok to use?

E.g. here:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t x = 0;
...
void f() {
  std::thread t([&] {x = 1;});
  while(x != 1) {/*waiting...*/}
  //done!
}
```

is it correct code?
Are there conditions it may not work?

Note: This is a over-simplifed example, i.e. I am not looking for a better solution for the given piece of code. I just want to understand what kind of behaviour I could expect from `volatile sig_atomic_t` in a multithreaded program according to the C++ standard. Or, if it is a case, understand why behaviour is undefined.

I've found the following statement [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic):

> The library type sig_atomic_t does not provide inter-thread synchronization or memory ordering, only atomicity.

And if I compare it with this definition [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order):

> memory_order_relaxed: Relaxed operation: there are no synchronization or ordering constraints imposed on other reads or writes, only this operation's atomicity is guaranteed

Is it not the same? What does exactly *atomicity* mean here? Does `volatile` do anything useful here? What's difference between "does not provide synchronization or memory ordering"  and "no synchronization or ordering constraints"?

Comment: It looks like the only guarantee it gives is that [it's signal safe](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t) I wouldn't use it for multi-threading. Based on the documentation for [`std::atomic_signal_fence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_signal_fence) I'd assume there are no ordering guarantees for anything 'signal' related.

Comment: Please check this: [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) it might fit better to your needs (not sure since you didn't provide a good description).

Comment: `volatile` means "give me the semantic of the underlying CPU and memory system". So the Q is inherently impl dependent (in theory). In practice, yes, it's the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using an object of type `sig_atomic_t` that is accessed by two threads (with one modifying).
Per the C++11 memory model, this is undefined behavior and the simple solution is to use `std::atomic<T>`

`std::sig_atomic_t` and `std::atomic<T>` are in different leagues.. In **portable** code, one cannot be replaced by the other and vice versa.

The only property that both share is atomicity (indivisible operations). That means that operations on objects of these types do not have an (observable) intermediate state, but that is as far as the similarities go.

`sig_atomic_t` has no inter-thread properties. In fact, if an object of this type is accessed (modified) by more than one thread (as in your example code), it is technically undefined behavior (data race);
Therefore, inter-thread memory ordering properties are not defined.

**what is `sig_atomic_t` used for?**

An object of this type may be used in a signal handler, but only if it is declared `volatile`. The atomicity and `volatile` guarantee 2 things:

- atomicity: A signal handler can asynchronously store a value to the object and anyone reading the same variable (in the same thread) can only observe the before- or after value.
- volatile: A store cannot be 'optimized away' by the compiler and is therefore visible (in the same thread) at (or after) the point where the signal interrupted the execution.

For example:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t quit {0};

void sig_handler(int signo)  // called upon arrival of a signal
{
    quit = 1;  // store value
}


void do_work()
{
    while (!quit)  // load value
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Although this code is single-threaded, `do_work` can be interrupted asynchronously by a signal that triggers `sig_handler` and atomically changes the value of `quit`.
Without `volatile`, the compiler may 'hoist' the load from `quit` out of the while loop, making it impossible for `do_work` to observe a change to `quit` caused by a signal.

**Why can't `std::atomic<T>` be used as a replacement for `std::sig_atomic_t`?**

Generally speaking, the `std::atomic<T>` template is a different type because it is designed to be accessed concurrently by multiple threads and provides inter-thread ordering guarantees.
Atomicity is not always available at CPU level (especially for larger types `T`) and therefore the implementation may use an internal lock to emulate atomic behavior.
Whether `std::atomic<T>` uses a lock for a particular type `T` is available through member function `is_lock_free()`, or class constant `is_always_lock_free` (C++17).

The problem with using this type in a signal handler is that the C++ standard does not guarantee that a `std::atomic<T>` is lock-free for any type `T`. Only `std::atomic_flag` has that guarantee, but that is a different type.

Imagine above code where the `quit` flag is a `std::atomic<int>` that happens to be not lock-free. There is a chance that when `do_work()` loads the value,
it is interrupted by a signal after acquiring the lock, but before releasing it.
The signal triggers `sig_handler()` which now wants to store a value to `quit` by taking the same lock, which was already acquired by `do_work`, oops. This is undefined behavior and possibly causes a dead-lock.
`std::sig_atomic_t` does not have that problem because it does not use locking. All that is needed is a type that is indivisible at CPU level and on many platforms, it can be as simple as:

```
typedef int sig_atomic_t;
```

The bottom line is, use `volatile std::sig_atomic_t` for signal handlers in a single thread and use `std::atomic<T>` as a data-race-free type, in a multi threaded environment.

Comment: In short, `volatile sig_atomic_t` does not guarantee *visibility* of a change outside of handling a signal.  :-)

Comment: Ok. You are saying that sig_atomic _...may simply not become visible to a load..._ which is very close to _`memory_order_relaxed`: Relaxed operation: there are no synchronization or ordering constraints imposed on other reads or writes, only this operation's atomicity is guaranteed_. As for me, it sounds the same exactly (and yes, let's suppose it's `lock_free` or `atomic_flag`, not any `atomic<>`). So, could I conclude that behaviour is the same then? Or I should not do such assumptions and behaviour is undefined?

Comment: @kan _...may not become visible to a load..._ is just an example of how 'undefined behavior' may play out, but I'll remove that phrase because it is confusing.
Undefined behavior is all one needs to know.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `atomic` has very poor visibility guarantees. And poor semantics. Poor everything.

Comment: Sorry for a silly question, but why "`sig_handler` ... taking the same lock, which was already acquired by `do_work` is an oops and UB? Why won't `sig_handler` just wait until the lock is released by `do_work`?

Comment: @Evg Not a silly question.. Reason is that everything is happening in the same thread of execution.. There is only a single order in which instructions are executed.
So if `sig_handler` is waiting to acquire the lock that is already held by `do_work`, neither function can make any forward progress and the entire thread is in deadlock.
With multiple threads, that problem is non-existent

Comment: @LWimsey, got it. Thanks!