# Why is volatile not part of sig_atomic_t

Tags: c++, signals, volatile

On my platform (X86, Fedora, gcc 9.1.1) `sig_atomic_t` is typedef'd to a plain `int`.

In the C++ standard, `sig_atomic_t` is always used with the `volatile` qualifier.
I understand why `volatile` is needed, but why is it not part of the type then  ?

Something like:

```
using sig_atomic_t = volatile int;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is inherited from C.  The C definition, while allowing for `sig_atomic_t` to be volatile qualified, does not require it.  All the example uses in the standard doc I've looked (N1570) at are given as `volatile sig_atomic_t`.

These days it may be better to use `std:atomic` and the other capabilities specified in the `<atomic>` header [when feasible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598970/stdatomicint-memory-order-relaxed-vs-volatile-sig-atomic-t-in-a-multithreade/56600194#56600194).  (Also see [sig_atomic_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/sig_atomic_t) on cppreference.)

Comment: In portable code, `std::atomic` is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598970/stdatomicint-memory-order-relaxed-vs-volatile-sig-atomic-t-in-a-multithreade/56600194#56600194) for signal handlers because there is a potential risk of deadlock. Also, but less important, the default seq/cst makes it stronger than necessary

Comment: @LWimsey I've toned down that recommendation a bit.

Answer (score 3):

[C89](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.7) says that it's

> the integral type of an object that can be accessed as an atomic
>   entity, even in the presence of asynchronous interrupts.

volatile not specified, probably because qualifiers were a new thing when the first standard was made.

[C99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.14p2) adds "possibly volatile-qualified.

I suppose it's backwards compatibility from then on combined with "nobody cares enough", since signal-handling is a relatively minor part of most project.

Also somebody could presumably use it in a context where volatile is not required (e.g., to store a copy of a flag used for communication with signal handlers) and in non-GNU C (again, backwards compatibility) it's basically impossible to map a type to a less qualified version of that type, which makes an implementation that chooses to omit the qualifier more flexible.